# How do I get the anomaly group id for aws lookout for metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to locate the anomaly group id for my anomaly detector with [Amazon Lookout Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lookout-for-metrics/index.html). There were no anomalies detected for my dataset but I want to invoke [`get_feedback()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lookoutmetrics.html#LookoutMetrics.Client.get_feedback) programatically and do something with the results, as I do not know where or how to locate the group id